# How to manipulate the speed of the thread during sorting algorithms simulation

Tags: multithreading, model-view-controller, user-interface, sorting

My question is in regards to a Java project I am currently working on. I have to build a simulation to show the workings on various different sorting algorithms conceptually/visually. These include: bubble sort, insertion sort, merge sort and some others. This must allow the user to either step through each step of the process or select a speed they wish it to execute at. This must be done with the use of a thread. The sorting algorithms are all inside one class and whichever one the user chooses from the from end will run within the thread.

e.g. sort.bubbleSort(objects); < objects being an array of objects to be sorted.

My problem is that I don't know how to manipulate the speed of the thread. For step by step I will need it to pause after each line of the algorithm is executed for example. This project also implements MVC. The thread is in the Contoller package and the sorting class is in Model. Anyone that can help me with this it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any magic bullet type solution.  I think you are going to have to put `Thread.sleep(...)` calls in your code in various places.

```
public class BubbleSort {
    private long sleepBetweenIterationsMillis;
    public BubbleSort(long sleepBetweenIterationsMillis) {
       this.sleepBetweenIterationsMillis = sleepBetweenIterationsMillis;
    }

    ...
    // iterate through the list bringing the highest value to the top
    // wait a certain number of millis
    Thread.sleep(sleepBetweenIterationsMillis);
    // loop
    ...
}
```

Picking the points in your sorting algorithms to put those sleep calls depends on what you consider an "iteration" to be.  Instead of injecting a sleep value, you could instead make a call to some sleep manager which could change the sleep values dynamically or something based on user input.

```
public interface SleepManager {
   public void sleep();
}

public class BubbleSort {
    private SleepManager sleepManager;
    public BubbleSort(SleepManager sleepManager) {
       this.sleepManager = sleepManager;
    }

    ...
    // iterate through the list bringing the highest value to the top
    // call the manager which can dynamically slow or speed up the iterations
    sleepManager.sleep();
    // loop
    ...
}
```

I can't comment on the MVC questions.  You are going to have to write another more specific question around what you have tried and what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Just to add to Gray's suggestion, I think you could make good use of `System.currentTimeMillis()` to get the time at the beginning of execution and check it periodically to determine how long of a delay you need at that point in the program (this would be useful if the data to be sorted is variable).

Comment: Thanks @Youssef.  I'm worried that using the `currentTimeMillis()` may level the playing field amongst the sorting algorithms.  I think the OP is trying to show the fast or slow algorithms.  You wouldn't want bubble-sort which is N^2 to sleep less per iteration.

Comment: ohhhhhh!! @Gray...so is the requirement saying that depending on the chosen speed, a different algorithm will be picked?  Can we get clarification from the questioner?

Comment: No @Youssef.  I'm just saying that the delays should be constant per run regardless.  You wouldn't want to shift the delays to be smaller the longer it has been running.

Comment: @YoussefG The user gets to choose which sort they would like to be demonstrated at the beginning. They will then be shown a visualisation of each element in the array being moved around. They choose the speed they would like this to happen also at the beginning.

Comment: @Gray Further to the second section of code in your answer. How is it that the BubbleSort class can be controlled by the SleepManager?

Comment: @Granttastic I was just showing you how you could use a `volatile` variable so you could tune the sleep millis on the fly during the iterations.